# Set up flags of library in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I'm compiling with library mylib.so, in which there are several flags to be set up, flagA and flagB. The following is my current Makefile:

```
MYLIBS=$(realpath ../lib/mylib.so)
MYLIBS_OPTS=-mllvm -flagA=true -mllvm -flagB=true
MYCXX=$(realpath ../bin/clang++) -Xclang++ $(MYLIBS) $(MYLIBS_OPTS)
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -ggdb
```

Then I compile the library with my code by

```
mycode: mycode.c
    $(MYCXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^
```

But when I run `make mycode` in terminal, I got the following errors:

```
clang (LLVM option parsing): Unknown command line argument '-flagA=true'.  Try: 'clang (LLVM option parsing) -help'
clang (LLVM option parsing): Unknown command line argument '-flagB=true'.  Try: 'clang (LLVM option parsing) -help'
```

I think I might have missed something. Really appreciate any help!

Comment: `-l` options should go in `LDLIBS`; other library-related options should go in `LDFLAGS`

Comment: Looks like llvm doesn't like those flags. What flags are you really using?

Comment: I'm using flags that are defined in mylib.cpp, which turned into mylib.so, not the ones defined in llvm.

Comment: Then why are you passing the flags to the compiler?

Comment: I can only decide the flags when I'm compiling a specific project. It there anywhere else I can pass the flags?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by flags, then. Are you talking about macro definitions? It would really help if you provided a [mcve].

Comment: I'm guessing these are supposed to be preprocessor macros, in which case the proper way would be to add `-DflagA=true` to the `CPPFLAGS` make variable (`CPPFLAGS` = C PreProcessor flags). `-Dfoo=bar` tells the preprocessor to define a macro `foo` with value `bar`.